# fp.write writes extra newlines to file

Tags: python, django

So I have a form in Django, where user inputs some text. Then I write this text to a file.

My views.py looks something like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    code = request.POST.get('code', False)

    fp = open('mp/somefile.txt', 'w')
    fp.write(code)
    fp.close()
```

However this causes extra newline characters. (I am using windows)

for example

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
```

results in

```
aaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbb

cccccccc
```

Is there a way to prevent these extra newline characters?

Comment: try fp.write(str(code).replace("\n", ''))

Comment: Thanks it works! Would this work in linux as well because eventually I will be deploying this application on a linux based server.

Comment: Yes, it should work in linux also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    code = request.POST.get('code', False)

    fp = open('mp/somefile.txt', 'w')
    fp.write(str(code).replace("\n", ''))
    fp.close()
```